# How to install logitech setpoint

Tags: software-installation

Ive googled all day and cant find setpoint for ubuntu anyone wish to tell me how

Ive tried google
Searching these fourms
Wiki
Random webpages friends

Nothing worked :(

Comment: i see that i helped have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Solaar package](https://launchpad.net/~daniel.pavel/+archive/ubuntu/solaar) may provide the functionality you are looking for.  For example, pairing a mouse and keyboard to a single receiver.

Comment: I solved this issue long ago and now no longer use Ubuntu, I have switched to Kali :/

Comment: Can I program the buttons with this software?